# How to create copy to clipboard icon without input filed?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this Vue.js code:

```
      <div class="border">
        <h4>{{ name }}</h4>
        <div class="code">
          <p>{{ code }}</p>
          <img src="~/assets/img/copy.svg" alt="" @click="copy"/>
        </div>
      </div>
```

There is `copy` function on copy button. What I want is to copy `code` field in clipboard. I was looking for a solution on the internet, but there were solutions only for `input` filed, but, as you can see, I have just paragraph.

I was trying to use `ref` and `id` on that paragraph, but it doesn't work. With `ref`:

```js
<p ref='code'>{{ code }}</p>
```

```
copy() {
  this.$refs.code.focus()
  document.execCommand('copy')
}
```

With `id`:

```js
<p id='code'>{{ code }}</p>
```

```
copy(id) {
  const input = document.querySelector(`#${id}`)
  input.setAttribute('type', 'text')
  input.select()
  document.execCommand('copy')
  input.setAttribute('type', 'hidden')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

> Html

```
   <p id="text_element">Copy this !</p>
   <button onclick="copyToClipboard('text_element')">
   Copy to clipboard
   </button>
```

> Javascript

```
function copyToClipboard(elementId) {
var aux = document.createElement("input");
aux.setAttribute("value", document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML);
document.body.appendChild(aux);
aux.select();
document.execCommand("copy");
document.body.removeChild(aux);}
function log() {
console.log('---')
}
```

Comment: `"message": "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerHTML')",`

Comment: replace `elementId` this with the id of element